# Removing a member based on a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I would like to design a vector class with small vector optimisation. It looks like:

```
template <typename T, int small_size = 0>
class Vector {
private:
    T data_small_[small_size];
    T* data_;
    T* size_;
    T* capacity_;
public:
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, most of the time, the class will be used with small_size = 0. Is there a way to remove data_small_ for small_size = 0 without going into template specialisation and rewriting the whole code for the class?

Comment: Usually you would do a template specialization, but not of the whole Vector, of a base class.

Comment: Are you using 'data_small_' when small_size == 0? If not, the compiler will probably remove it as dead code when you instantiate the class with small_size = 0.

Comment: @James: If small_size = 0, it is not used by the code. But I don't think that the compiler would remove it as it affects sizeof(Vector<T, 0>).

Comment: @Marc: Hi Marc. I am not that experienced with C++ and the only usage of inheritance I do is with abstract classes. Could you please elaborate on what you would use?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [empty base optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) here. You would have to change `Vector` to not refer to `data_small_` directly. Instead, write use `SmallData` to implement the required member functions and handle the `small_size = 0` case in the partial specialization `SmallData<T, 0>`. Below is an example with `SmallData` implementing a copy constructor and `operator[]` and `Vector` using them without worrying about `small_size`.

```
template <typename T, int small_size>
class SmallData
{
 public:
  SmallData(const SmallData& other)
  {
   for(size_t i = 0; i < small_size; i++)
     data_small_[i] = other.data_small_[i];
  }

 T& operator[](int k){return data_small_[k];} 
 protected:
  T data_small_[small_size];
};

template <typename T>
class SmallData<T, 0>
{
 public:
 T& operator[](int k){//throw some error} 
};

template <typename T, int small_size = 0>
class Vector : public SmallData<T, small_size>
{
 public:
 Vector(const Vector& other) : SmallData<T, small_size>(other)
 {
  //rest of copy ctor either here on in the member init list above
 }
 T& operator[](int k)
 {
  if(k<small_size) return SmallData<T, small_size>::operator[](k);
  else return data_[k];
 }
};
```

Comment: The idea looks nice. But how do you write the methods? It would be nice to have a static_if but it does not exists in C++. Many methods will be the same whatever small_size is but some will depend upon its value, like a copy constructor.

Comment: @InsideLoop How about allowing `SmallData` to handle all of that? Don't treat `data_small_` as an array of `T` inside `Vector`. Instead have `SmallData` expose whatever array semantic you need. That way, you get to move all the `small_size=0` handling up into the `SmallData<T,0>` specialization. This might end up being cleaner than having to deal with it in `Vector`. And if that doesn't suffice, you are stuck with tag-dispatching or sfinae on `small_size==0` I guess.

Comment: I am not sure to get it yet. Let's be concrete. For instance T& operator[](int k) { return data_[k] } will be the same whatever the value of small_size is (data_ will point to data_small_[0] when small size optimisation is effectively used in the case where small_size > 0). On the other hand, copy constructors will be different depending upon the value of small_size. So where do you declare them? Could you give me a code example?

Comment: But there is no member called `data_small_` in `Vector<T,0>` if you use my suggestion. So, instead, you would have something like this in `SmallData`. Master template would have `SmallData::operator[](int k){return data_small_[k];}` and `SmallData<T,0>::operator[]` would `throw` if called. For copy constructor, you have it easy since `SmallData` is the base of `Vector`. Something like `Vector(const Vector& other) : SmallData(other) {//Copy Vector specific stuff}`. And ensure that `SmallData`'s copy ctors are good.

Comment: I get it (and updated my previous comment to me more clear). When small_size > 0, data could be either stored in data_small_ on the stack or data_ on the heap. Would you mind addind T& operator[](int k) in your code  (whose code does not depend upon small_size) and a copy constructor (whose code depends upon small_size).

Comment: I don't think you can define SmallData::operator[](int k){return data_small_[k];} . It might be that small_size = 5 and the vector has 10 elements in it. In this case, there is no data in data_small_ and everything is in what data_ points to (on the heap). Also, you loose efficiency if you can the copy constructor of (other) in the case where nothing is stored in data_small_.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Unfortunately, for efficiency reason, I can't put a if in T& operator[](int k) that is not evaluated at compile time. I think I really can't afford a full template specialisation in my case.

Comment: You can make it `T& operator[](size_t k)`. This will allow compilers to optimize out the `if` when `small_size == 0`. But you are still stuck with it when you have a positive `small_size`.